# ipython install new modules

Tags: python, module, installation, pip, ipython

I am used to the R functionality of installing packages and I am trying to do the same thing with `ipython`. Sometimes the following method works but then again sometimes it doesn't and I would like to finally find out why it only works half the time.

Normally to install a module (like the `requests` module for example) I would type the following after opening a fresh terminal:

```
$ sudo pip install requests
Password: *******
```

This would then be followed by a message indicating that the install was successful or that it has already been installed.

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): 
requests in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

Which suggests that the code can be accessed. And indeed if I run python now from the terminal it shows a good response without any errors whatsoever.

```
$ python
ActivePython 2.7.2.5 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 24 2011, 12:20:15) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>>
```

I now open `PyLab` through Alfred and it gives me an error.

```
Welcome to pylab, a matplotlib-based Python environment [backend: WXAgg].
For more information, type 'help(pylab)'.

In [1]: import requests
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/vincentwarmerdam/<ipython-input-1-686486c241c8> in <module>()
----> 1 import requests

ImportError: No module named requests
```

I've read some help from another question on StackOverflow ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663046/how-to-install-a-python-package-from-within-ipython?rq=1)) which suggests that I install the module from `ipython` shell. This gives an even more baffling response:

```
In [2]: !pip install requests
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in     
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...

In [3]: import requests
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/vincentwarmerdam/<ipython-input-3-686486c241c8> in <module>()
----> 1 import requests

ImportError: No module named requests
```

This seems very strange to me. Are there multiple versions of python installed on the system? How could I check this? Do I need to point `ipython` to the location of the installed code?

Comment: I don't know what Alfred is, but what happens if you just try to import requests in an ipython session without pylab/alfred?

Comment: Alfred is a shortcut app. I tried running ipython instead of pylab. I get the following: ```$ ipython```

```In [1]: import request```

```ImportError: No module named request```

Seems like the same error.

Comment: try to `import sys ; print sys.path` in iPython to see if the install directory is included.

Comment: one thing to check is the value of `sys.executable` when you are in plain Python and IPython, or alternately the value of `head -n 1 $(which ipython)` and `head -n 1 $(which pip)` to make sure they are using the same Python.

Comment: ```$ head -n 1 $(which ipython) ``` gives 
```#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python ``` and 
```$ head -n 1 $(which pip)``` gives
```#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 ```

so i need to include the 'pip-folder' to the 'ipython-folder' if i understand correctly? i still don't understand why ```pip install requests``` in ipython tells me that the library is installed while the folders are not correct.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

actually there is a much much much more elegant solution. when pip is installed then within python you can do things like this as well:

```
import pip

def install(package):
   pip.main(['install', package])

install('requests')
```

which is easier. once logged into a virtualenv you can just make sure that you have what you need in the session you are in. easy.

#### edit

Another alternative would be to use the `%%bash` magic.

```
%%bash
pip install requests
```

#### edit2

If you want the standard output, one could even use the exclamation bang.

```
! pip install requests
```

#### edit3

From within `ipython` this is the safest installation method.

```
%pip install requests
```

This ensures that everything is installed in the virtualenv that your `ipython` is installed in.

Comment: not to my knowledge. but you can install pip easily from easy_install and maybe you should: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install

Comment: I get permission denied for the first approach, is it possible to somehow have that run as sudo?

Comment: be careful. you can run `sudo jupyter notebook` followed by these commands but this will cause *EVERY* command to run with `sudo` priviledges which can be a huge security risk.

Comment: if you can ensure that you're in the correct environment from the command line you can also use `sudo pip install <package>` which is much safer. you just have to ensure that you've got the correct python environment.

Answer (score 7):

Here's what I did that made it work; open up iypthon through the command line and type

```
import sys
sys.path
```

This shows a list of folders where other python modules are located. For me this was:

```
['',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/bin',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.10.0-py2.7-macosx-10.5-i386.egg',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googlemaps-1.0.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth-1.0.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2-1.5.211-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.7.7-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.28.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jellyfish-0.2.0-py2.7-macosx-10.5-i386.egg',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_yelp-0.1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo-2.4.2_-py2.7-macosx-10.5-i386.egg',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lucene_querybuilder-0.1.6-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize-0.2.5-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/html2text-3.200.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python27.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/vincentwarmerdam/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions]
```

With this information, I now knew where ipython looks for the modules that one can import. So I downloaded the requests library manually, added it to the same root directory such that the following directory exists:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests
```

This folder contains the python modules that belong to requests. The only thing I now had to do was to make sure that ipython knows that this folder exists. Which was done by updating the sys.path.

```
req_link = '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/requests'
sys.path.append(req_link)
```

After this I no longer got the error.

```
import requests
```

Just works.

Also after restarting ipython, I found that ipython automatically updates the new path into the `sys.path` list.

Answer (score 0):

If the new packages installed are imported on Terminal but not imported to ipython notebook then it is very likely that you have two versions of python installed on your library. Due to this there are separate site-packages directory from where packages are being imported on terminal and ipython notebook. To check if this is the case.
On terminal use:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

This will show where the python modules are located for python you using on terminal.
Now, in ipython notebook use:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

This will show where the python modules are located for python you using on terminal.

Now, if the two path are different you know you are using two different installations of python. To solve this problem, copy installed packages from site-packages directory of terminal python to site-packages directory of ipython.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem when trying to install patool, but it turned out it was due to more than one interpreter installed, and when I ran it from ipython it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This sorted me out running Spyder on Windows.
As the answer above, to find the directory:

`import sys`

`sys.path`

This site :
[www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-pip-on-windows/](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-pip-on-windows/)

Directed me to this: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

Use cmd to run that script from the directory of the version of Python you want to add modules to. Then just use pip to add the modules, again from the command line.
I didn't even bother adding any of it to my PATH, but you could do that.