# I cannot import tensor flow inside the jupyter notebook but I can import that in terminal python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Why does this happen? I'm using the same python kernel.

When I import tensor flow in terminal python, it works fine.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc.) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import tensorflow
>>>
```

However, when I try to open ipython notebook and import it does not work:

---

```
ImportError       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-a649b509054f> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow

ImportError: No module named tensor flow
```

Why?

Comment: Are you sure that the python of IPython is the same as the other ??

Comment: Why is there a space in the message for your `ImportError`? Also, can you check `sys.path` in both contexts?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the package for tensorflow to get it to work. 
Check this post out:
[ipython install new modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974100/ipython-install-new-modules)

Comment: If that were the problem, the import wouldn't work from the Python shell either. IPython does not require separate installation of packages unless the environment is configured differently somehow.