# Install new package from inside ipython Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am new to Python. I wonder if is it possible to install a new package from inside iPython Notebook.

I tried `pip install address` but it returns error:

```
pip install address
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes you can

Use the following syntax:

```
!pip install packagename
```

[Reference thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663046/how-to-install-a-python-package-from-within-ipython)