# Installing a new module in IPython

Tags: python, ipython

I'd like to install the pygame package through IPython but when I try the command suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663046/how-to-install-a-python-package-from-within-ipython),

```
!pip install pygame
```

I get the following error:

```
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

What should I do? If it helps, I'm on Windows 10 and Python 3.6.1. Thanks!

Comment: `pip` is for Python 2.x. `pip3` is for Python 3.x. You have Python 3.6.1. Which command should you use?

Comment: On Windows, [as explained here](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtualenv/#windows) as well as in the official docs, it's usually recommended to use `py -m pip` (or `python -m pip` if you're not using the `py.exe` launcher, or `C:\path\to\specific\python -m pip`, etc.).

Comment: @ForceBru That's usually not true on Windows. `pip` will either be accessible on the PATH as `pip`, or not at all, even for 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

As the Python Packaging Authority docs on [Installing packages using pip](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtualenv/#windows) explain, on Windows, you usually don't want to use `pip` directly. It may not be on your `PATH`, or it may be on your `PATH` but not match the same version as the `py.exe` launcher.

Usually, you want to use that `py.exe` launcher for everything:

```
py -m pip install pygame
```

If you're not using `py.exe` for some reason, the answer is usually one of these:

```
python -m pip install pygame
D:\path\to\specific\python -m pip install pygame
```

[The official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html) mention the `python` version first, and only mention `py` for when you're dealing with multiple Python versions. But you're probably better off always using `py`, as the PyPA suggests. See [PEP 397](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/) for why the launcher is useful.)

---

Of course if you want to do this from inside IPython instead of directly at the shell, prefix any of those with `!`.

---

As a side note: Notice that the same page pretty strongly recommends using `virtualenv` (or the builtin `venv`, but the documentation is all for `virtualenv`). You should consider doing so, but if you have a good reason not to, it's not mandatory or anything.