# How to install Python packages for Python 3.6.5 for Windows 10

Tags: python, scikit-learn, installation

While installing I faced syntax error:

```
>>> pip3 install numpy
```

File "", line 1
    pip3 install numpy
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
>>> pip install -U scikit-learn
```

File "", line 1
    pip install -U scikit-learn
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Please tell me how to install the packages required and if I am missing any pre-requisites.

Comment: You're typing those commands at the Python prompt. `pip` is not a Python command. Issue `pip` commands at a shell prompt.

Comment: To add to the comment by @kindall, if you do want to install packages from within iPython you can check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663046/how-to-install-a-python-package-from-within-ipython).

Comment: @kindall Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the pip command in a terminal or cmd instead of the Python prompt.

Open a terminal or command prompt and just type

```
pip3 install numpy
```