# Import recognition executing Python script from C#

Tags: c#, python

I'm trying to execute a simple Python script from C# program. The Python script imports cv2 and numpy. This script works when executing from command line, but cannot find cv2 when executing from C#. I'm using Anaconda3, IronPython, Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015 Profesional. I'm new to Python, but I think this may be a path/location problem.

**The instruction:**

`engine.ExecuteFile(@"C:\Development\Test.py");`

gives the following exception:

> "No module named cv2"

See the code below:

```cs
Using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;

namespace EmbededPyConsoleTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           ExecutePythonScript();
        }
        private static void ExecutePythonScript()
        {
            ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
            engine.ExecuteFile(@"C:\Development\Test.py");
        }
    }
}
```

```
Python test script:

import cv2
import numpy as np
-
-
-
-
```

Comment: Are any of the files used by Python on a Network drive? I have had issues when full pathnames exceed around 120 characters.

Comment: You are probably using different interpreters with different installed packages. To find out your interpreter path: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589711/find-full-path-of-the-python-interpreter . To install packages to ipython: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663046/how-to-install-a-python-package-from-within-ipython

Comment: Thanks G.B. So Anaconda and IronPython use different interpreter? As I said, I'm new to Python. I can say that the Test.py runs fine from the Anaconda3 power shell prompt, which is using the environment and interpreter I set up. The error only occurs when I run the C# program, which  uses IronPython for creating the engine, but I have no idea what that entails or what needs to be identified. It may well be a case of two interpreters, but I'm not sure what to do about it. IronPython package was obtained with NuGet, if that helps.

Comment: Thanks jdweng. All files are on my PC.

Answer (score -2):

I found the problem. I needed to include:

using IronPython.Runtime;
using IronPython;